# a closed subset $F$ of $Q^{C} \cap [0,1]$ has continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

CAn we find a closed subset $F$ of $Q^{C} \cap [0,1]$ such that $I_{Q^{C} \cap [0,1]}$ (where the indicator function on the irrationals in $[0,1]$) is continuous on $F$ and $m([0,1]-F) < \epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon>0$.

I think the answer depends on Lusin theorem, but not sure how to find the closed set explicitly.

Comment: What is $I_{Q^C\cap[0,1]}$?

Comment: the indicator function on the irrationals in $[0,1]$.

Comment: This seems to me to be just an application of Lusin´s theorem then, what am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean continuous on $F$ (i.e. that you want that $\left.I_{[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q}\right\rvert_F:F\to\Bbb R$ is continuous) or do you mean that the function should be continuous at all points of $F$ (i.e. that $I_{[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q}$, as a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, is continuous at all points of $F$)? Because for the first interpretation the condition is irrelevant, seeing as $F\subseteq A$ implies that $I_A$ is constant on $F$, and the second interpretation is just false because $I_A$ is $1$ on $F$ and the zero set of $I_A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: the first one, and I need to find a particular closed set $F$ explicitly. I know it is an application of Lusin theorem, but Lusin theorem just guarantee the existence of the closed set and does not determine it exactly.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Can we find a closed subset $F$ ?